# Confusion related to gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution

I have this confusion related to gaussian distribution

Do we need to have something like $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ to be called gaussian or $e^{-{x^2}}$ is enough to be called Gaussian. I was reading this article related to gaussian integral and they don't even have the fraction 1/2 to be called gaussian. I mean it can be called gaussian function. But is it gaussian distribution?

Comment: It's strictly not a distribution but you may still call it Gaussian distribution up to a normalization constant.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang. You mean if I used a normalization constant Z such that the integral is 1, then I can still call it gaussian distribution?

Comment: @rajansthapit Yeah, standard normal distribution

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Not *standard* since the variance will be $\frac12$.

Comment: @Did Yes, it is since $f(x)\propto e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, so $\mu=0, \sigma=1$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang No. The OP is talking about $\mathrm e^{-x^2}$.